# Creation of a new Form

Tags: forms, delphi, button

I updated my code and looked over it. The problem is when I try to generate NextButton4 and NextButton3 with procedure TForm2.Next1Click(Sender:TObject) in AForm(which is my Form that is created by TForm2.Button1Click) it won`t work like i can not see NextButton4 and NextButton3 in AForm. Delphi tells me that it is possible that AForm could not be intialized in line 117 (which says  NextButton3 := TButton.Create(AForm);) but i do not know how to fix it. Sorry that I did not explain it very well. (the clickable component for TForm2.Next1Click(Sender:TObject); is NextButton1).
My aim is to create a working ToDoList. For that I need a Mainform where Button1 is located. Button1 when clicked now creates lists/folders (AButton) on the Mainform(Form2) and a new form(AForm) where is now located NextButton1 and NextButton2. Now I want to store memories, task,... in AForm thats why i need two more Buttons (NextButton3 and NextButton4). NextButton2 should just close the form (AForm). And NextButton1 should, if clicked, create 2 Buttons (NextButton3 and NextButton4) and another form(NextForm). At the End I want to add one panel in AForm to store memories and tasks(did not add the panel yet). NextButton4 should open NextForm. In NextForm you can edit the Panel i did not create yet (f.e. change colour or name of the memory/task). The Problem with this is that NextButton3 and NextButton4 is created(I think) but i can not see it. Hope you can understand what I wrote.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Generics.Collections;

type
      TFormItem =  record
      AForm       : TForm;
      NextForm    : TForm;
      AButton     : TButton;
      NextButton1 : TButton;
      NextButton2 : TButton;
      NextButton3 : TButton;
      NextButton4 : TButton;
  end;
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FList1    : TList<TFormItem>;
    FList2    : TList<TFormItem>;
    procedure MyClick   (Sender:TObject);
    procedure Next1Click(Sender:TObject);
    procedure Next2Click(Sender:TObject);
    procedure Next3Click(Sender:TObject);
    procedure Next4Click(Sender:TObject);
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Item        :  TFormItem;
    AButton     :  TButton;
    AForm       :  TForm;
    NextForm    :  TForm;
    NextButton1 : TButton;
    NextButton2 : TButton;
    NextButton4 : TButton;
begin
    AButton         := TButton.Create(Self);
    AButton.Tag     := FList1.Count;
    AButton.Left    := 80;
    AButton.Top     := 50 + AButton.Tag * 60;
    AButton.Width   := 300;
    AButton.Height  := 50;
    AButton.Name    := 'Liste' + IntToStr(1+AButton.Tag);
    AButton.Caption := 'Liste' + IntToStr(1+AButton.Tag);
    AButton.OnClick := MyClick;
    AButton.Parent  := Self;

    AForm           := TForm.Create(Self);
    AForm.Tag       := AButton.Tag;
    AForm.Left      := AButton.Tag;
    AForm.Top       := AButton.Tag;
    AForm.Width     := 1000;
    AForm.Height    := 700;
    AForm.Name      := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+AButton.Tag);
    AForm.Caption   := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+AButton.Tag);
    AForm.Parent    := nil;
    AForm.Visible   := FALSE;

    NextButton1         := TButton.Create(AForm);
    NextButton1.Tag     := FList1.Count;
    NextButton1.Left    := 20;
    NextButton1.Top     := 560 ;
    NextButton1.Width   := 170;
    NextButton1.Height  := 70;
    NextButton1.Name    := 'Erinnerung_hinzufügen';
    NextButton1.Caption := 'Erinnerung_hinzufügen';
    NextButton1.OnClick := Next1Click;
    NextButton1.Parent  := AForm;
    NextButton1.Visible := true;

    NextButton2         := TButton.Create(AForm);
    NextButton2.Tag     := FList1.Count;
    NextButton2.Left    := 800;
    NextButton2.Top     := 560;
    NextButton2.Width   := 170;
    NextButton2.Height  := 70;
    NextButton2.Name    := 'Ok';
    NextButton2.Caption := 'Ok';
    NextButton2.OnClick := Next2Click;
    NextButton2.Parent  := AForm;
    NextButton2.Visible := true;

    Item.AForm   := AForm;
    Item.AButton := AButton;
    FList1.Add(Item);

end;

procedure TForm2.Next1Click(Sender:TObject);
var
    NextForm    : TForm;
    AButton     : TButton;
    Item        : TFormItem;
    AForm       : TForm;
    NextButton3 : TButton;
    NextButton4 : TButton;
begin

    NextButton3         := TButton.Create(AForm);
    NextButton3.Tag     := FList2.Count;
    NextButton3.Left    := 240;
    NextButton3.Top     := 2 + NextButton3.Tag * 60;
    NextButton3.Width   := 75;
    NextButton3.Height  := 25;
    NextButton3.Name    := 'Einstellungen' + IntToStr(1+NextButton3.Tag);
    NextButton3.Caption := 'Einstellungen' + IntToStr(1+NextButton3.Tag);
    NextButton3.OnClick := Next3Click;
    NextButton3.Parent  := AForm;
    NextButton3.Visible := True;

    NextButton4         := TButton.Create(Self);
    NextButton4.Tag     := FList2.Count;
    NextButton4.Left    := 120;
    NextButton4.Top     := 2 + NextButton4.Tag * 60;
    NextButton4.Width   := 75;
    NextButton4.Height  := 25;
    NextButton4.Name    := 'Einstellungen' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextButton4.Caption := 'Einstellungen' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextButton4.OnClick := Next4Click;
    NextButton4.Parent  := AForm;
    NextButton4.Visible := True;

    NextForm           := TForm.Create(Self);
    NextForm.Tag       := NextButton4.Tag;
    NextForm.Left      := NextButton4.Tag;
    NextForm.Top       := NextButton4.Tag;
    NextForm.Width     := 1000;
    NextForm.Height    := 700;
    NextForm.Name      := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextForm.Caption   := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextForm.Parent    := nil;
    NextForm.Visible   := false;

    Item.NextForm   := NextForm;
    Item.NextButton4 := NextButton4;
    FList2.Add(Item);
end;

constructor TForm2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;
    FList1 := TList<TFormItem>.Create;
    FList2 := TList<TFormItem>.Create;
end;

destructor TForm2.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(FList1);
    FreeAndNil(FList2);
    inherited;

end;

procedure TForm2.MyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Item : TFormItem;
begin
    Item := FList1[(Sender as TButton).Tag];
    if Assigned(Item.AForm) then
        Item.AForm.Show;
end;

procedure TForm2.Next2Click(Sender:TObject);
var
    Item : TFormItem;
begin
     Item := FList1[(Sender as TButton).Tag];
     if Assigned(Item.AForm) then
        Item.AForm.Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.Next3Click(Sender:TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm2.Next4Click(Sender:TObject);
var
   Item : TFormItem;
begin
     Item := FList2[(Sender as TButton).Tag];
     if Assigned(Item.NextForm) then
        Item.NextForm.Show;
end;
end.
```

Comment: "But this wont work" is not enough. Describe which behavior you have with your code and which you should have. And remember you can use the debugger to better see what happens. Searching by yourself is the best way to learn. We are not supposed to do the homework assigned to you...

Comment: I cannot tell from what you wrote what you're trying to accomplish. You're having a problem with a form. And you're apparently trying to create everything on the form at run-time, which is typically only done if you're creating a component. It would help immensely to start off by explaining what you're trying to do and why you're taking such an unusual approach vs. what Delphi is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi was absolutely right in saying that "AForm might not have been initialized". After all, `AForm` is a local variable of `procedure TForm2.Next1Click()` and you don't assign anything to it before you use it, as an owner in this case:

```
NextButton3         := TButton.Create(AForm);
```

Later you write:

```
NextButton4         := TButton.Create(Self); // self is your Form2!!
```

You also need `AForm` as a valid object to assign as parent for the buttons you create later in your code

```
NextButton3.Parent  := AForm;
NextButton4.Parent  := AForm;
```

If I have understood correctly, there might be a chain of new forms created and the parent of `NextButton3` and `NextButton4` is different from case to case. We can however use the `Sender: TObject` to identify the `NextButton` that is clicked. And when we know the button, we ask for its parent to know the form.

So, add this to beginning of TForm2.Next1Click to set `AForm`:

```
if TButton(Sender).Parent is TForm then
  AForm := TForm(TButton(Sender).Parent);
```

Then you will also need to modify the `Name` (to avoid name clashes) and `Caption` assignments, for example:

```
//    NextForm.Name      := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextForm.Name      := AForm.Name + '_' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
//    NextForm.Caption   := 'Erinnerung' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
    NextForm.Caption   := AForm.Name + '_' + IntToStr(1+NextButton4.Tag);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it really helped me out and the program is running likt I hoped it would

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `TForm2.Next1Click` you'll need to add:

```
AForm.Show;
```

Also, in `TForm2.Next1Click` the warning you get is correct: `AForm` here is a *different* variable that needs to get its value from somwhere, and here doesn't get a value at all, so may contain `nil` or worse still, a value made up of anything that happened to be stored in the memory Delphi will be using when this event handler is called.

If you need it to be the same value as a reference to the form you created in `TForm2.Next1Click`, you'll have to store the value somewhere. For example in the global `var` clause just above `implementation`, or a private member in `TForm2`.

For example if you add `Form3:TForm;` between `var Form2:TForm2;` and `implementation`, add

```
Form3:=AForm;
```

at the end of `TForm2.Next1Click` and

```
AForm:=Form3;
```

at the beginning of `TForm2.Next1Click`